# Getting Web service response in string Format

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am using Afnetworking Framework in my project but I am getting the response in string format. I want to get the value of "Data" in the response below -

```
"{\"Result\":\"Success\",\"Data\":\"intro-1898-1449000428650.mp4\"}"
```

I have used the code below:

```
[Helper PostWebServiceRequest:kIntrovideo InputParameters:parameters competion:^(BOOL result, NSDictionary *response) {
    if (result){
        NSLog(@"response : %@",response);

        NSString *data=  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",response ];

        NSError *jsonError;
        NSData *objectData = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since your response object seems to be an array and not (as stated) a dictionary, try the following:

```
NSString *jsonString = ((NSArray *)response).firstObject;
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
NSString *data = jsonObject[@"Data"];
```

Comment: hello sorry for replying late. i have used as you mention but the app is crashing and the error is as below--[__NSCFArray objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x787c4c90
2016-04-11 03:00:07.512 StaffingEvolution[1789:129588] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x787c4c90'

Comment: so `response` is an array and not a dictionary as stated in your code?

Comment: i don't know how the response is coming in the string Format

Comment: i want to convert this response in dictionary

Comment: type is "__NSCFArray"

Comment: ok, and can you please show me the exact output of your statement `NSLog(@"response : %@",response);`...

Comment: here is the output- response : (
    "{\"Result\":\"Success\",\"Data\":\"intro-1898-1449000428650.mp4\"}"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108766/discussion-between-andre-slotta-and-jatin-vashisht).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but it seems that server can't pass object in Json, it's should pass link to place from where you can download this Data.